# Why int and Integer in parent-child relationship always print int in java?

Tags: java, java-8, integer

I am trying to print Integer value in below code snippet but everytime its gonna print int block. Why this is happening?

```
class A {
    void methodOne(int i) {
        System.out.println("int " + i);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    void methodOne(Integer i) {
        System.out.println("Integer " + i);
    }
}

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        a.methodOne(10);
        a.methodOne(new Integer(10));
        B b = new B();
        b.methodOne(20);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
int 10
int 10
int 20
```

Why it always print int, not integer?

Comment: This has ***nothing*** to do with Swing! Don't add irrelevant tags.

Comment: Did you try `b.methodOne(new Integer(20));`?

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple answer to your question. I'll justify the output for each case followed by the solution. Before that, some notes about your code snippet:

- As class `B` extends `A`, and has the same method `methodOne` with a different  type of parameter (`Integer`), it has two overloaded versions of method `methodOne`.
- `A a = new B();` Here, `a` is an instantiation of `B` and of type `A`.

Justifications:

1. `a.methodOne(10)`: The type of parameter `10` is `int`. So `void methodOne(int i)` of class `A` is invoked.
2. `a.methodOne(new Integer(10))`: The type of parameter `new Integer(10)` is `Integer` but the method `methodOne(Integer i)` in the subclass `B` is not visible to `a`. Thus `new Integer(10)` is unboxed to `int 10` and again `void methodOne(int i)` of class `A` is invoked.
3. `b.methodOne(20)`: As `b` is an instantiation of `B`, it has both the versions of method `methodOne`. But type of parameter `10` is `int` and thus again `void methodOne(int i)` of class `A`(its parent class) is invoked.

The solution:

```
B b = new B();
b.methodOne(new Integer(20));
```

Here, the type of the parameter `20` is `Integer`. So the `void methodOne(Integer i)` of class `B` is invoked.

Here's a little experiment that can help you understand the non-visibility of methods of the subclass in parent class. Place a dummy method in class B and try to access with the object of type `A` but **instantiation of type `B`**. Following is the modified code.

```
// Place this method in Class B
void test(){

}

//In the main method
A a = new B();
// a.test();  
// The test method will not be available in class `A`, though the instantation of `a` is of type `B`.
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is related to AutoBoxing and Auto Unboxing. Having this lines common for both scenarios, please note that this example is **not** related to method **overriding**.

```
A a = new B();
a.methodOne(10); /* line 1 */
a.methodOne(new Integer(10)); /* line 2 */
B b = new B();
b.methodOne(20); /* line 3 */
b.methodOne(new Integer(20)); /* line 4 */
```

Scenario 1:

```
class A {
    void methodOne(Integer i) {
        System.out.println("Integer " + i);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    void methodOne(int i) {
        System.out.println("int " + i);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Integer 10 /* line 1, [AutoBoxing] */
Integer 10 /* line 2 */
int 20     /* line 3, B has method(int) */
Integer 20 /* line 4, B has method(Integer) */
```

Scenario 2

```
class A {
    void methodOne(int i) {
        System.out.println("int " + i);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    void methodOne(Integer i) {
        System.out.println("Integer " + i);
    } 
}
```

Output

```
int 10     /* line 1 */
int 10     /* line 2, [auto unboxing] */
int 20     /* line 3 */
Integer 20 /* line 4 */
```

Answer (score -2):

```
class A {
    void methodOne(Integer i) {
        System.out.println("Integer " + i);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    void methodOne(int i) {
        System.out.println("int " + i);
    }
}

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        a.methodOne(10);
        a.methodOne(10);
        B b = new B();
        b.methodOne(20);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will print
Integer 10
Integer 10
int 20

Comment: Sure.  So how does this answer the question?  OP wants to know why something is happening.  A bunch of code without an explanation won't really help anyone.

Comment: Due to auto-unboxing. 
The result will be different in the question where -> if I put Integer I in class B and int i in class A, because the class A will contain int as parameter, thus resulting in the Integer getting unboxed, and the method is being called. Class B will contain both methodOne due to extending to class A, which will in turn automatically called methodOne of class A, thus printing int i. I will therefore swap the parameters between class A and B.

Answer (score -2):

Class B extends Class A and due to this reason it also contains the methods of Class A.

That's why, **when you call methodOne(), you call methodOne() of Class A from Class B because Class A is the main class while Class B is the subclass of Class A.** So, Class A is taken first and that's why it prints 'int' from Class A's methodOne() instead of priting 'Integer' from Class B' methodOne().

*Solution:-*
**Rename Class B's methodOne() to 'methodTwo()' or any other name, and call that method where you want to print 'Integer'.**

Comment: Changing the method _name_ is clearly not the solution. The OP asks about the reason for such behavior. You can get the desired answer `Integer 10` even without changing the method name.

Comment: The reason is that Class A is the main class while Class B is the subclasss.That's why, Class A is referenced first before Class B.

Comment: I dont know what's your problem is with e and why you downvoted while I answered the question correctly, decribing the cause too.